# GenericRecord to SpecificRecord object using Avro

Tags: c#, .net-core, avro, confluent-platform

I use `Confluent.Kafka.Avro` for serialization between producer and consumer for Apache Kafka. From producer I use specific record, but on consumer side I want consume all records as generic and then convert them to specific records. Is there any way to do this automatically? Or need to implement all this conversion?

Comment: I don't think you can cast an class to a more specific type, in general. Like if you had an `Animal` class, you couldn't make it `Dog` or `Cat` just given an instance of `Animal`

Comment: @cricket_007 GenericRecord in Kafka.Avro have information about serialized type. I just want to know if Kafka.Avro already have this implementation or need to implement this by myself.

Comment: I'm saying `GenericRecord` in Avro cannot be cast into a `SpecificRecord`, even though, yes the generic record may contain a schema property

Answer (score 2):

If you have the specific record and you know you can convert to that, you should use Kafka's `SpecificRecord` deserializer. I believe the only situations in which converting to `GenericRecord` in your Kafka consumer makes sense is when you know that the Avro content cannot be deserialized using your current specific data classes, because either you don't have any specific data classes for that data (the schema / message is not known in advance), or the schema has changed in an incompatible way, and so the data cannot be deserialized into your current `SpecificRecord` classes. Neither of these situations could apply to you as you explicitly say you have the `SpecificRecord` classes necessary.

That being said, as per my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59442020/430128, you *can* convert an Avro `GenericRecord` to a `SpecificRecord` using `deepCopy`:

```
SpecificData.get().deepCopy(genericRecord.schema, genericRecord)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement it yourself, though, the solution isn't really related to Kafka because once you consume and deserialize the data, you can manipulate that information however you can.

However, In the Specific Avro deserializer, it will not accept a GenericRecord type because [Generics don't implement `ISpecificRecord` or are subclasses of `SpecificFixed`](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/csharp/src/apache/main/Generic/GenericRecord.cs)

```
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"{nameof(AvroDeserializer<T>)} " +
                "only accepts type parameters of int, bool, double, string, float, " +
                "long, byte[], instances of ISpecificRecord and subclasses of SpecificFixed."
            );
        }
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka.Avro/SpecificDeserializerImpl.cs

If you're going to convert to a SpecificRecord anyway, then you should just use the SpecificRecord Deserializer