# Is it possible to convert a generic record to specific record with the same schema?

Tags: java, avro

I have a GenericRecord object of schema A, which is also a generated Avro Java class. Is it possible for me to cast this object into actual A type somehow?

Answer (score 5):

You can convert an Avro `GenericRecord` to a `SpecificRecord` using `deepCopy`. For example, if "Foo" is the specific record:

```java
Foo foo = (Foo) SpecificData.get().deepCopy(genericRecord.getSchema(), genericRecord)
```

This assumes that the `SpecificRecord` class corresponding to the schema passed is available to Avro.

Note that this approach does not support schema evolution: there is only one schema passed to the `deepCopy` and it is used for both reading and writing. This means the fields are copied based on their position, so the `SpecificRecord` schema must match the `GenericRecord` schema exactly.

See http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/Direct-conversion-from-Generic-Record-to-Specific-Record-tp4029324p4029339.html.

Comment: The reverse operation didn't work for me.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877855/avro-record-deserialization-issue

Comment: I dont understand this code. It's still a genericrecord after the deepCopy, where is the specificRecord?

Comment: @LunaticJape I've updated the answer so hopefully it is clearer now. Basically, if Avro finds a SpecificRecord class corresponding to the passed schema, it will instantiate it and return it during the `deepCopy`.

Comment: I got this error.   java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ReservationStatusReason cannot be cast to class org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord (com.ReservationStatusReason and org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord are in unnamed module of loader 'app').
I have my concrete class included in one of my dependencies.

Comment: @LunaticJape Perhaps a schema mismatch? Try passing `ReservationStatusReason.schema` as the first parameter instead of `genericRecord.schema`. Also check if `genericRecord.schema.equals(ReservationStatusReason.schema)`.

Comment: ReservationStatusReason is a java pojo class, it does not have `.schema`.

Comment: @LunaticJape Well, that's your problem. Your class needs to implement the `SpecificRecord` interface.