# GenericRecord to POJO

Tags: java, apache-flink, avro

I am consuming from Kafka Avro record and creating a GenericRecord Stream. Now for some computation I want to convert GenericRecord to Pojo Object. I have already generated a class using Avro-maven-plugin from the schema.

But I am not able to convert the generic record to This generated class Object.

Please help me how to do this. I want to know how to implement **ConvertoPojo** function in the below code.

```
    public void flatMap(Tuple2<Long, GenericRecord> recordTuple2, Collector<Tuple4<Long, Long, Long, Long>> collector) throws Exception {
        GenericRecord record = recordTuple2.f1;
        String event_name = record.get("event_name").toString();

        if (event_name.equals("search_list_keyless")) {
            SearchListKeyelss object = ConvertoPojo(record)
        }

        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227389/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-generic-record-to-specific-record-with-the-same-sche/59442020#59442020