# Avro: Record deserialization issue

Tags: deserialization, avro

I have a SpecificRecord object from which I want to read a property from. Lets assume that I do not have access to the generated class of this SpecificRecord object (since these are dynamically chosen at runtime from a pool of classes via Reflection). Every generated class does have a common property "EXTRACT_DT_TM" (and a getter method for it) that I want to be able to read from this SpecificRecord object (Which is what I am having issues with).

So far I have tried:

```
    public String map(SpecificRecord record) {
        System.out.println("genericData to String = " + 
        GenericData.get().deepCopy(record.getSchema(), record).toString());
        GenericRecord genericRecord = (GenericRecord) 
        GenericData.get().deepCopy(record.getSchema(), record);
        System.out.println("genericRecord to String = " + genericRecord.toString());

        Long extractionTime = (Long) genericRecord.get("EXTRACT_DT_TM");
```

But I get the following exception:

```
  2021-08-22 01:14:43,280 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord
    at com.x.y.analytics.ods.z.ExtractionDatePartitionFn.map(ExtractionDatePartitionFn.java:49)
    at com.x.y.analytics.ods.wolfe.ExtractionDatePartitionFn.map(ExtractionDatePartitionFn.java:22)
    at org.apache.crunch.fn.ExtractKeyFn.map(ExtractKeyFn.java:64)
    at org.apache.crunch.fn.ExtractKeyFn.map(ExtractKeyFn.java:29)
    at org.apache.crunch.MapFn.process(MapFn.java:34)
```

Looking for any thoughts on how to read this value from the SpecificRecord.. In the above approach, I was trying to convert a SpecificRecord to a GenericRecord and then read the value from it..

Answer (score 0):

For now since the position of the property is fixed across all generated classes, I was able to use the following. I would still like to know if anyone has a better answer that is not tied to the index.

```
        Long extractionTime = (Long) record.get(2); // EXTRACT_DT_TM field
```